# One user couldn't be assigned as owner of the record using dataloader

Tags: ownership

I am looking around 5000 records using dataloader, where i am also assigning the ownerid for each account record.  I have around 80 records couldn't be inserted because of the issue "invalid cross reference id".  Everything looks the good, only common thing with these record was they all belong to the same owner.  I looked upon the owner, he has never logged into his account and he has a role where noone else has, his profile looks as a standard user profile.  Please help.

Anything else i need to look into?

Answer (score 1):

Is that user active? You should get "Operation performed with inactive user" error but maybe there are multiple problems...

Standard user you say... but is he a regular user or somebody with say Chatter Only license? Does he have "Read" right to the Accounts?

Do these records have a weird record type for example? One that you're not allowed to use? It doesn't matter that you're System Administrator - check your Profile for rec. type availability.

Do you have anything else there that does any kind of matching via lookup? Maybe you have some external ids that don't resolve nicely? Maybe in row N+1 you're creating account whose parent was row N and if that one has failed - everything below will fail? (but again, I'd expect a more descriptive error in that case).

Answer (score 0):

The user has never logged in before, i see no activity for this user. he is not a chatter user, he does have rights on accounts.  i checked my record type availability but don't see anything there.

how else should i verify the record type for sys admin?

Comment: (I think you should have put it as comment under my answer or edit the original question rather than post a new non-answer ;)) But one more idea. What happens when you take one existing record and assign to him? or if you run Apex with similar content? `insert new Account(Name = 'test', OwnerId = 'that guy', RecordTypeId = '...');` - write it similar to what's in that Data Loader's file. Maybe there are some triggers at play? Enable debug logging and fire?

Comment: i am new to both(site and sf), excuse my learning curve.  Through UI i couldn't change the ownerid, in lookup that owner was not listed.  Through trigger i didn't know what to put in the recordTypeid, can you help?

Comment: If you cannot see the user in the lookup he's probably inactive. Check his user record, look for "Active" checkbox. You'll have to activate him in order to select him as the owner. You can upload your data and then deactivate him again if you wish but most likely your business users will want to nominate different owner in that case

Comment: Thank you so much, got it.  It was a new user, they(sales director) added without my knowledge and i was working in the sandbox without any idea of this.  Now i will refresh my sandbox.